# How can I splice out the date from similar strings?

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of dates from some web scraping, but it seems that a country is also in the date string.  Here is a sample:

```
Nov. 4, 2015Bangladesh 
April 8, 2015Saudi Arabia 
Jan. 14, 2016Indonesia 
June 26, 2015Tunisia 
Jan. 11, 2016France
```

I know regex is really great for working with strings, but I am just not experienced enough to know how to start.

How can I remove the country while keeping the dates intact?

Answer (score 3):

This regex will get you just the date string from all of those. This could probably also be fixed by showing us your code for scraping the dates, but that's not what this question is about.

```
^.+?\s\d+,\s\d+
```

Example:

```
import re
dates = ["Nov. 4, 2015Bangladesh",
"April 8, 2015Saudi Arabia ",
"Jan. 14, 2016Indonesia ",
"June 26, 2015Tunisia ",
"Jan. 11, 2016France "]


for item in dates:
    print(re.match(r"^.+?\s\d+,\s\d+", item).group(0))
```

This prints:

```
Nov. 4, 2015
April 8, 2015
Jan. 14, 2016
June 26, 2015
Jan. 11, 2016
```

Explanation

```
^    -assert position at start of string
.+?  -match any char except newline (as few as possible)
\s   -match a space character
\d+  -match any number of digits
,    -match literal comma
\s   -match a space character
\d+  -match any number of digits
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try following:

[`^(.*\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/sH5tI5/1)

Check the demo [here](https://ideone.com/hUyGGJ):

```
import re

dates = """Nov. 4, 2015Bangladesh 
April 8, 2015Saudi Arabia 
Jan. 14, 2016Indonesia 
June 26, 2015Tunisia 
Jan. 11, 2016France"""

print re.findall(r'^(.*\d{4})', dates, re.M)
# ['Nov. 4, 2015', 'April 8, 2015', 'Jan. 14, 2016', 'June 26, 2015', 'Jan. 11, 2016']
```